# Associate Xcode Commits with TFS 2013 Work Items

Tags: xcode, git

I'm testing out the new Team Foundation Server 2013 Git integration from an Xcode project. The basics are working fine, but I'm trying to determine if I can associate a commit with a TFS work item without leaving Xcode or using additional tools.

I found this [screencast](http://blog.nwcadence.com/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013-xcode-and-git-with-tfs-2013/) which shows that adding `My commit message for #6` (or whatever the work item ID is) to the commit message will allow TFS to make the association, but this does not work for me at all.

I've tried it with tasks, bugs, and product backlog items all without any success.

I've also seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933236/associating-git-commits-with-team-foundation-work-items), but I was hoping the simple approach from the screencast I mentioned above would work.

Does adding # plus a work item ID work for anyone else in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled across this by accident.

If my commit message is `Fix for bug #4` the link is NOT made.

If my commit message is `Fix for bug #4 <space>` (with an extra space at the end), the link is NOT made.

If my commit message is `Fix for bug #4 blah blah` (with seemingly any other text at the end), the link IS made correctly.